# Search and replace pop down in Obj-C app

Tags: objective-c, macos

Hi all I just wanted to know if anyone could point me to a link or show me how to implement a search & replace like in TextEdit 1.7 on Lion, or in Xcode 3.2 (when you click on CMD + F). There is a little pop down that appears and I would very much like to implement a similar search field.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

"An NSSearchField object implements a text field control that is optimized for performing text-based searches. The control provides a customized text field for entering search data, a search button, a cancel button, and a pop-up icon menu for listing recent search strings and custom search categories." [NSSearchField](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSearchField_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class reference.

Comment: Hi Graham, I meant a search field included in a drop-down sheet-like object.

Comment: ... like in this here picture, which is a shot of the latest version of TextEdit for Lion : http://grab.by/aG1V

Comment: you'll have to construct your own view to do that. should be very straight-forward..